# RegEx for consecutive numbers that starts with prefix 00

Tags: java, regex

Have to validate the values **0020**,**0021**,**0022**,**0023** while generating a report.

I have tried the below :

```
Pattern.compile("^00[20,21,22,23,]").matcher(value).matches()
```

But instead of getting true i'm getting it as false.

Could anyone please help me on this

Comment: You need to validate the comma-seperated string or just those 4 different values? If the latter, just use `^002[0-3]$`

Comment: What about `"^00(20|21|22|23),"`?

Comment: Thanks after using ^002[0-3]$, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

```java
Pattern.compile("00(20|21|22|23)").matcher(value).matches()
```

`,` is not OR operator , regex OR is `|`.

Comment: `^` is redundant as `.matches` requires a full string match.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.matches` to match the whole string,  you can put `002` outside of the character class, and `0` `1` `2` and `3` instead the character class without the comma's.

```
002[0123]
```

Or 1 character shorter with a range.

```
002[0-3]
```